# How to gain access to the SPI port on any Android phone

Tags: hardware

I am a hardware developer and want to connect my hardware board by hacking into the SPI port of a form factor Android Phone.  My objective is to connect my board using jumper wires to a Smartphone to create a near form factor demo. (my board size is about 2" x 3")

My questions are as follows

1. Do any of you know an easy way to gain access to the SPI bus on any Android Phone?
2. Can these Android phones be re-flashed after making the required changes to the Kernel to support my board?

Comment: Just as an FYI, hardware hacking questions are pretty far outside the ken of this site. While not explicitly off-topic (I don't think, anyway) I don't know that the people you're trying to reach hang out here. We're more about helping people use their Android device _as is_.

Comment: I think you might have more luck with this kind of questions over at [electronics.se].